# PHP Event booking: get time in increments of 30 minutes is 1 hour out

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, datetime

I am trying to get a select box with a list of time increments from 00:00 to 24:00.

The time increments are an associative array of seconds to the display time like this:

1800 => 00:30

Then when someone selects a date, I plan to convert the date (e.g. 2016/9/16) into seconds and then add the time that they selected on to those seconds to get the date time of their event.

To do this I am generating the time increments like this.

```
public function getIntervals($start_time = '00:00', $end_time = '24:00', $increments = '30')
{
    $today = strtotime(date('Y/m/d', time())); // seconds for 2016/9/16

    $seconds_start = strtotime(date('Y/m/d', time()) . ' ' . $start_time) - $today;
    $seconds_end   = strtotime(date('Y/m/d', time()) . ' ' . $end_time) - $today;

    while ($seconds_start < $seconds_end) {
        $intervals[$seconds_start] = date("H:i", $seconds_start);
        $seconds_start = strtotime('+' . $increments . ' minutes', $seconds_start);
    }
    return $intervals;
}
```

However my time intervals are one hour out.

[image]

If someone selected '2016/9/17 at **01:00** in the morning' the value in seconds of 01:00 in the morning is '**0**'.

If I add '**0**' to strtoseconds('2016/9/17') I am going to get '2016/9/17 at **00:00**'.

So here I am,one hour out. I assume this is due to my server time being set to paris +1hr, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Instead of `date("H:i", $seconds_start);` try `date("H:i", $today + $seconds_start);`

Comment: basic rule of thumb: if you're doing date math, and your results are always out by some exact multiple of 60, it's almost always a timezone issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$timediff = 3600;

$paris_00_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d '.'00:00'));

$paris_selected_time = $paris_00_time+1800;

$my_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$paris_selected_time-$timediff);

print_r($my_time);
```

you can declare `$timediff=3600;`  ( 1  hour )

`$paris_00_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d '.'00:00'));`

after someone choose the date ( ex: `[1800] => 00:30` ) and is submitted you can process the date

`$paris_selected_time = $paris_00_time+1800;`

`$my_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$paris_selected_time-$timediff);`

output: 2016-09-15 23:30:00

Answer (score 1):

I don't really remember where, but you can change your timezone. Search by PHP timezone and you will find from the official website a list with all the possible country/city. You just need to set a variable with the country/city you need and that's it. I don't know if you can do it in your PHP script or need to change your config files in the server.

Comment: Here are the links your answer is missing. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php, http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php